# Solving a linear system having an unknown matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose we have a set of $N$ pairs of vectors $\{x_i,y_i\}$ such that each pair satisfies the linear equation $y_i=Ax_i$ where $A$ is an unkown matrix. If we are given a new vector $x$, is there a procedure to get an approximation for $y$ that will satisfy $y=Ax$ with the help of  $\{x_i,y_i\}$ ?

Comment: Not if the $x_i$ are random. If they form a basis of the vector space, then you can write $x=\sum_i \lambda_ix_i$ hence $y=\sum_i\lambda_iy_i$ by linearity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume for the moment that the $x_{i}$ are independent. Complete them to a basis $B$ of the underlying vector space.

Now write $x$ in terms of this basis
$$
x= \sum_{i=1}^{N} c_{i} x_{i} + b,
$$
where $b$ is a linear combination of the remaining basis vectors.

Then all you can say is that
$$
y = \sum_{i=1}^{N} c_{i} y_{i} + A b.
$$

If the $x_{i}$ are linearly dependent, then either the equations $$y_{i} = A x_{i}\ \qquad i = 1, \dots , N$$ are not consistent, and then there's really no such $A$, or the equations are consistent, and then they are equivalent to a subset of them, for a choice of a subset of the $x_{i}$ that is a basis of the space spanned by all $x_{i}$. In other words, if the equations are consistent, you may assume the $x_{i}$ to be independent.